How to "check manually" for updates from drush/programmatically
Using the Nagios module, my dashboard alerts me when there are updates available for Drupal modules.  However, the notification remains until someone initiates a check for modules needing updates, even with a cache rebuild.
It looks like in the past, drush pm:refresh or drush pm:update-status could refresh the "needs update" status, but those aren't in modern drush.  Is there a mechanism by which I could update this via CLI?

Does drush cron help? Then schedule a cron job in the cron table of your web server, you need this for other important tasks as well.

It will not. Update's cron will only execute when check.interval_days have passed.

OK, this is because you don't need to check for new module versions every time cron runs, but in my experience people not seeing updates don't run cron.

Run cron, from the command line drush cron, but better put a link to cron.php in the crontab of your web server.
By default, update checks are configured once per day. For high-traffic sites it's recommended to run cron more often, but that doesn't affect the update checks, to protect the community servers from too much traffic.

The currently-supported procedure is to use composer outdated. Useful flags exist like -D which will check only declared dependencies, and --locked, which looks directly at the lock file rather than requiring composer install to have been run.

A direct way with Drush for the existing behavior is:
drush php:eval "update_refresh();"
drush php:eval "update_fetch_data();"

